# Адаптировать меню на CSS

Tags: html, css

Есть меню, все бы ничего, если она не скакала то вниз, то вверх в зависимости от того, сколько дюймов монитор. Как мой CSS можно адаптировать меню?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu {
  background: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  /* делаем не подвижный блок */
  top: 135px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 41%;
}

#mainmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  float: left;
  font: 20px;
  height: 40px
}

#mainmenu ul li {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 40px
}

#mainmenu ul li a {
  color: #fde31c;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 35px;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#mainmenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #0aff30;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="DROB.php">
        <h3>Дробильная</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ROF.php">
        <h3>РОФ</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Filtr.php">
        <h3>Фильтрация</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правельно понял меню должно быть постояно внизу.
Тогда вместо `top:135px;` дайте `bottom:0;`и удалите `margin-top:41%;`, по этому оно у вас и скачет

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainmenu {
  background: #000000;
  position: fixed;
  /* делаем не подвижный блок */
  bottom:0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
}

#mainmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  float: left;
  font: 20px;
  height: 40px
}

#mainmenu ul li {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 40px
}

#mainmenu ul li a {
  color: #fde31c;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 35px;
  width: 190px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#mainmenu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #0aff30;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="DROB.php">
        <h3>Дробильная</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="ROF.php">
        <h3>РОФ</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="Filtr.php">
        <h3>Фильтрация</h3>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее)